# How to set a role for a member list? discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

const membersWithRoleRadiant = message.guild.roles.cache.get('957714551011442781').members

membersWithRoleRadiant.roles.set(['955804233284878367']);

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')

I received a list of participants with a specific role, I would like to set a different one for each.

Comment: The way to do this is with API spam, which you should not do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This is written for Discord.js v13.4.0.*

---

### `.roles` is not a property

Your issue is that you are calling the `roles` property on a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/general/welcome) of `GuildMember`. This doesn't work because [Collections](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/general/welcome) are a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) but modified. You would have to perform `.each()` and apply the role that way. It'd look something like this:

```js
membersWithRoleRadiant.each(member => member.roles.set(['IDHere']);
```

A small advisory as well. You should be careful when updating roles for a lot of users at once. This can be considered API spam which will cause Discord to rate limit or shut down your bot.

### Reconsider using `.set()`

If you are only adding or removing roles, I **strongly discourage** the usage of `.set()`. That method will remove all their roles and replace it with the ones you have supplied. If you are adding roles, use the [`.add()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/13.4.0/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) method. Use the [`.remove()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/13.4.0/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=remove) method when removing roles.